# Should I use XMPP(or other protocol) for chat when I already use AMQP(RabbitMQ)

Tags: .net, xmpp, chat, rabbitmq

I need to implement chat between users in my application(.NET). I'm already using RabbitMQ as message broker in it to pass some notifications between client programs. Is it normal to use RabbitMQ for creating integrated chat or its better to use XMPP to implement chat part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control both the chat clients and chat server, then you will find it easier to use AMQP for your chat as well. You might want to use a separate topic exchange for the chat messages though.

XMPP makes sense when you need to support 3rd party chat clients or chat servers.

Comment: Did that already, thank you..Works just fine, but was wondering if its "normal" to do that with amqp.